# Adding specific function to the pipeline (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I created a pipeline, it contains scaler, one hot encoder and xgboost algorithm.
After that i want to apply RandomizedSearchCV.

But i was doing imputer process before every process;
Let me explain;

```
my_imputer_func:
 doing calculations according to the columns
creating pipeline
do RandomizedSearchCV
```

So, this imputer function must be in pipeline to avoid data leakage.

```
def dataframe_imputer(X):
    for i in X.columns:
        if 'ratio' in i:
            X=X[(abs(X[i])<=1) | (X[i].isnull())]
        if len(X[X[i].notnull()])/len(X)<1:
            if i[0:2]=='z0':
                imp=SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0)
                imp.fit(X[[i]])
                X[i]=imp.transform(X[[i]])
            elif X[i].dtype=='O':
                imp=SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent',missing_values=None)
                imp.fit(X[[i]])
                X[i]=imp.transform(X[[i]])
            else:
                imp=SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
                imp.fit(X[[i]])
                X[i]=imp.transform(X[[i]])
    return X

col_transformers = ColumnTransformer([
                          ("scaler_onestep", scaler, numerical_columns),
                          ("ohe_onestep", ohe, categorical_columns)])

model = MultiOutputClassifier(xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic"))

pipeline = Pipeline([("imputer",FunctionTransformer(dataframe_imputer)), ("preprocessing", col_transformers), ("XGB", model)])

param_grid = {
        'XGB__estimator__max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 10],
        'XGB__estimator__reg_lambda': [0.1, 1.0, 5.0],
        'XGB__estimator__n_estimators': [100]}

rs_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, n_iter=3,
                            n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, cv=2, scoring="accuracy", refit=True, random_state=42)

rs_clf.fit(X, y)
```

But i got following error;

---> rs_clf.fit(X, y)

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and
> 'NoneType'

It seems like the dataframe_imputer function not working.
How can I make this function work? Anyone have a suggestion? Or I can write the code in a different way.

Comment: Any "surprises" in `X` _after_ calling `dataframe_imputer(X)`?

Comment: What kind of surprises ? @rickhg12hs

Comment: I assumed, possibly incorrectly, that your `NoneType`s are coming from `X` in `rs_clf.fit(X, y)`, but perhaps there are `NoneType`s in `y` too/instead?

Comment: There is no nonetype in y :(

Comment: ... nor in `X` after calling `dataframe_imputer(X)`?